# Alternative to Order by in subquery for JPA

Tags: postgresql, jpa, criteria-api

I have a query which looks like this in postgres:

```
SELECT op.* 
FROM opportunity op INNER JOIN quote q ON q.id = 
    (SELECT q.id FROM quote q WHERE q.op_id = op.id 
     ORDER BY q.createddate DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE ((q.accepted = true) OR (q.rejected = false))
  AND op.op_type IN ('Type 1', 'Type 2')
```

The problem when translating it to JPA is that Subquery doesn't allow for Order by and limit so I'm stuck at this. Also not sure about how to join the tables:

```
        public Specification<Opportunity> cleaningOpps(Boolean withStatus, String[] statuses){
    return (root, query, builder) -> {

        List<Predicate> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        if(withStatus != null){
            Subquery<Quote> subquery = query.subquery(Quote.class);
            Root<Quote> quote = subquery.from(Quote.class);
            List<Predicate> subqueryFilters = new ArrayList<>();
            subqueryFilters.add(builder.equal(root.get("id"), quote.get("op_id")));
            //Some more filters for the subquery...
            subquery.select(quote).where(builder.and(subqueryFilters.
                    toArray(new Predicate[subqueryFilters.size()])));//Need group by and limit as well
            filters.add(builder.exists(subquery));
            Join<Quote, Opportunity> joinQuote = root.join("quotes");
            //Probably I'll use the joinQuote for some more filtering

        }
        //Some more filters...
        return builder.and(filters.toArray(new Predicate[filters.size()]));
    };
}
```

I don't know how to insert the order by and the limit in the subquery. Any workaround for this or any other idea other than doing it with native queries ?

Comment: What's the point of ordering and limiting in a subquery passed to EXISTS? You want to test the existence of something. The order doesn't matter, and the database is smart enough to not scan all the matching rows when just testing if one exists.

Comment: Well, I want to check that it exists in the last added quote, not in all of the quotes, that's why the order by createddate desc and limit 1

Comment: That's not what your subquery does. It selects all the quotes which have a given op_id, and then only takes the most recent one among these quotes.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The query is wrong, now I see. Sorry about that

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question, still kind of the same problem